# Where can I find build artifacts in Travis?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm new to Travis. The user docs are fantastic and I had little trouble getting my little project to build. But how do I get at the thing that was built? Can I?

- The build log shows my binary getting linked, but I see no way to access it.
- I'm not interested in automating deploys or uploads, I just want to see what was produced.

Comment: It was! Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any artifacts from builds are purged after a successful build, together with the build environment. Travis CI isn't explicitly storing them for you, but can be convinced to do so: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/